# Jquery .serializeArray() not getting selected text with value

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

My main issue is that I have to send data using serialize with id and serializeArray with selected text. I need both information selected value and selected text in 2 serialization, `serialize()` and `serializeArray()` respectively. Not changing much code in the blade.

```html
<form id="updateUser">
    <label for="name">Name</label> 
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="First and last name" tabindex="1" />

    <label>Agent Name</label> 
        <select name="user_id" id="user_id" >
          @foreach ($users as $user)
                <option value="{{ $user->id }}">{{ ucwords($user->name)}}</option>
           @endforeach
         </select>

    <input name="submit" type="submit" id="submit" tabindex="6" value="Send Message"/>

</form>
```

I then use jQuery to send AJAX request, serializing the form and save the data, then in `response.success` I send `serializeArray` to another function in js file.

```js
$.easyAjax({
            url: url,
            container: '#updateUser',
            type: "POST",
            buttonSelector: $(this),
            data: $('#updateUser').serialize(),

            success: function (response) {
                if(response.status == 'success'){
                  var form_data= $('#updateUser').serializeArray();
                    track("user store",form_data);
                 }
           });
```

this is the data in form_data when serializeArray

```
0:{name: 'name', value: 'abc'}
1:{name: 'user_id', value: '23'}
```

I tried this but how to send selected text of dropdown with value.

```
if(response.status == 'success'){
    var agent_name = $("#user_id option:selected").text(); 
    var form_data= $('#updateUser').serializeArray();
    track("user store",form_data);
}
```

`

Comment: What is the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution.

```js
$.easyAjax({
  url: url,
  container: '#updateUser',
  type: "POST",
  buttonSelector: $(this),
  data: $('#updateUser').serialize(),
  success: function (response) {
    if (response.status == 'success') {
      var form_data= $('#updateUser').serializeArray();
      var form_data_obj = {};
      $.map(form_data, function(n, i) {
        form_data_obj[n['name']] = n['value'];
        if (n['name'].includes("_id")) { 
          var id_value = $.trim($("#"+n['name']+" option:selected").text());
          var id_name = n['name'].substr(0, n['name'].indexOf("_id"));
          id_name = id_name + "_name";
          form_data_obj[id_name] = id_value;
        }
      })      
    }
  });
});
```